# Why is this sequence not uniformly convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

In this problem is explained that $f_n(x)$ is pointwise convergent, however not uniformly convergent. The explanation why is not unifromly convergent is also given. However I cannot understand it, when I use the  theorem below I get that limit of $f_n - f = 0$
Could maybe someone give me more detail answer why the sequence is uniformly convergent?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, I don't see $f_n(x)\to0$??

Answer (score 3):

Since $\displaystyle(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\left|f_n\left(\frac1{2n}\right)\right|=\frac n4$, you have $\displaystyle\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\left|f_n(x)\right|\geqslant\frac n4$. In other words, $\displaystyle\|f-f_n\|_\infty\geqslant\frac n4$ and, in particular, it is *not* true that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f-f_n\|_\infty=0$. So, the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: How do you get n/4?

Comment: When I wrote $\left|f\left(\frac1{2n}\right)\right|=\frac n4$, I meant $\left|f_n\left(\frac1{2n}\right)\right|=\frac n4$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Where the function is not zero, it is a parabola with zeros at $0$ and $\frac{1}{n}$. Thus, the maximum is right in the middle.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos no, I mean how did you find out that it  f_n(1/2n)= n/4 how did you come with n/4

Comment: Possibility 1: José plugged $1/n$ into the formula for $f_n(x)$ and got $n/4$. Possibility 2: He knew this as a result of some homework he did as a child.

Comment: @AndreasBlass but if you put 1/n in f_n(x) you get 0???

Comment: Sorry for the typo. To evaluate $f_n$ at $1/2n$, plug in $1/2n$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass It's number 1. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Nice answer, I have a question: the estimate $\text{sup} \{|f_n(x) \ | \ x\in[0,1] \} \geq n/4$ is valid because $\frac{1}{2n}\in(0,1/2) \subset [0,1]$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$? I mean, that estimate would not be valid in general if the $\text{sup}$ was done on an interval different from $[0,1]$, right?

Comment: @Dunkelheit Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to determine the **pointwise** limit. Let $x\in[0,1]$. For $n>1/x$, $f_n(x)=0$, so the pointwise limit is $0$.

As the explanation shows, we have $\|f_n\|_\infty=n/4$. Thus, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n\|_\infty=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n/4=\infty$ and using the theorem you quoted, the limit of the suprema diverging is equivalent to $f_n$ **not** converging uniformly.

Comment: Perhaps you mean: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n/4=\infty$ ?

Comment: I corrected this typo. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of convergence of a sequence in a normed(or in general metric space)space the sequence (fn) cannot converge to f because norm (here it is sup-norm) of (fn - f) >= 1/4 for all n.